# useState is not persisting when calling function in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my React project, I have two components: `ScheduleModal` and `CameraSchedule`. Below is the implementation for both:

ScheduleModal:

```
export default function ScheduleModal({ c, useSchedule }) {
    const [schedules, setSchedules] = useState([Schedule])
    const [fail, setFail] = useState(false)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const updateSchedule = (id, updSched) => {
        // update object in schedules
        if (...) {
            setSchedules(schedules.map(s => {
                return s.id === updSched.id ? updSched : s
            }))
        }
        // add object to schedules
        else {
            setSchedules(prevSchedules => {
                return [...prevSchedules, updSched]}
            )
        }
    }    

    const postSchedule = async () => {
        ...makes a POST request with schedules...
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Modal disabled={!useSchedule} identity={c.IP} title={`Schedule for ${c.Name}`} openLabel="View Schedule" cancel="Cancel" save="Save" onSave={postSchedule}> 
                <CameraSchedule propSched={schedules} updateParent={updateSchedule} />
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
```

CameraSchedule:

```
function CameraSchedule({ propSched, updateParent }) {
    const addToSchedules = () => {
        const currDate = new Date()
        currDate.setMinutes(currDate.getMinutes() - currDate.getTimezoneOffset())

        # some uniqueId
        let newId = -1
        const newStart = currDate.toISOString().slice(0, 16)
        const newEnd = currDate.toISOString().slice(0, 16)
        const newRepeat = false

        const schedule = new Schedule(newId, newStart, newEnd, newRepeat)
        
        updateParent(newId, schedule)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <table className={style.table}>
                <thead>
                    <tr className={style.topRow}>
                        <td className={style.dates}>Start Date</td>
                        <td className={style.dates}>End Date</td>
                        <td>Repeat</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {scheduleRows}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <Button onClick={addToSchedules}>Add to schedules</Button>
        </div>
    )
```

The Modal component has a Save button that triggers the postSchedule function in ScheduleModal.

When I trigger addToSchedule in CameraSchedule and update the "schedules" state in ScheduleModal, the CameraSchedule component re-renders with the correct information (i.e. an additional schedule is displayed and stored in propSched). However, when the save button is pressed, and the code reaches PostSchedule, the "schedules" state no longer has the added schedule and only contains the number of items.

**What I've tried**:
I've checked my code back to see if I'm setting schedules anywhere else in the code. There's a useEffect that triggers on initial render, but doesn't trigger again during any callbacks. I've tried adding the below snippet ScheduleModal to ensure there aren't any extra renders, and the last thing printed to console is the correct schedule.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(schedules)
})
```

What's even weirder is that when I change an item in schedules (ex. schedules[0] changes end date), the change does persist and the updated item in the array is sent in the POST request.

So the error is most likely something specifically to do with adding to schedules.

Comment: "when the save button is pressed, and the code reaches PostSchedule, the "schedules" state no longer has the added schedule and only contains the number of items."
Just making sure I get this correctly, you mean it contains a number instead of your array?
Can you update the post so we know more precisely what's in your `postSchedule` function?